# MongoDB : aggregate query matching multiple conditions for subdocument array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a collection named engineer, which has one document :

```
{
  id : *some mongodb id*,
  username : "xyz",
  email id : "xyz@gmail.com"
  profession : [
      {
      id : *some mongodb id* ,
      location : "Moscow",
      licence : "civil engineer"
      }
      {
      id : *some mongodb id* ,
      location : "Berlin",
      licence : "cs engineer"
      }
]
}
```

I have a projects collection which has three documents :

```
{   
        "_id":"5ebaa72c9ad5010017a2179b"
        "projectName":"test project 1", 
        "status": "open"
        "licence":"cs engineer",
        "location":"Berlin",
        "description":"This is project",
        "duration":20,
 } ,
{   
        "_id":"5ebaa72c9ad5010017a2178b"
        "projectName":"test project 2",
        "status": "open"
        "licence":"civil engineer",
        "location":"Berlin",
        "description":"This is project",
        "duration":10,
 } ,
{   
        "_id":"5ebaa72c9ad5010017a2177b"
        "projectName":"test project 3",
        "status": "open"
        "licence":"civil engineer",
        "location":"Moscow",
        "description":"This is project",
        "duration":30,
 }
```

I have a "bids" schema. The schema looks like :  (to store necessary data when an engineer bids on a project)

```
{
    "projectID": : "*some project _id"       // will be a project id
    "bids": [{
        "bidAmount":
        "engineerID": 
    }]
    "__v": 1
}
```

My Question : 
I want to populate only those projects on which the engineer has **not** placed a bid and also i want to match the location and licence of the engineer with that of the project so that he can view projects with respect to his licence and location. So if you take the above sample data , I just want my result to have details of "**test project 1**" and "**test project 3**".

Sorry for such a lengthy explanation just wanted people to understand when they read it.
Appreciate any sort of help.
Thank You!!

UPDATE :

I tried with this aggregation query :

```
// match.location = ['Moscow' , 'Berlin']
// match.licence = ['civil engineer' , 'cs engineer']

const project = await BidHistory.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      'bids.engineerID': { $ne: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.engineer.id) }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'projects',
      localField: 'projectID',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'project'
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {       
          'project.location': { $in: match.location },
          'project.licence': { $in: match.licence }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      bids: 0,
      projectID: 0,
      _id: 0,
    }
  }
]);
```

But with the above query i am getting unnecessary data. If you apply this query on my sample data. I am getting back **test project 2** also in my result which I do not want. I know its because of the $in operator but I cant find a way around it!

NOTE : An engineer can have just one **location and licence** too

Comment: So do you start this aggregation on `project` collection ? what are your inputs ?

Comment: I assume there will be no bid document for a project that has no bids? Or there is always a bid document for each project but the `bids` array can be empty?

Comment: Better question: is it possible to have a bid document that contains empty `bids` array?

Comment: @TheeSritabtim yes! A bid document is created with empty bids array every time a new project is created. So there will always be a bid document  for a project  but the bids array can be empty. Thank you.

Comment: @whoami I would like to start the aggregation on bid document using the projectID to lookup for all the projects in the project collection. But the condition is i want only those projects on which the engineer has not placed a bid and also the engineers location and licence should match with it! Thank You

Comment: I assume you want to start on bid *collection*? not *document* ? And do you want to match with only one particular engineer which you retrieved earlier?

Comment: @TheeSritabtim hi! suppose there is an engineer  whose id is "x". If an engineer has bid on a project his id will be stored in the bids array under that particular "projectID" . In the bids array of that projectID the id "x" will be stored against "engineerID". So I want to gather all the bid documents which does not have the id "x"(basically when engineer has not bid) take the projectID of those gathered documents get the projects using the projectID and filter the project documents according to engineers license and location

Comment: In that case, you have already retrieved the engineer with the id "x", right? So you would know which `licence` and `location` to look for. Or do you want to start the aggregation with finding the engineer?

Comment: @TheeSritabtim No i do not want to retrieve engineers. I want to retrieve the projects with respect to the engineers location and licence so that engineer views only those projects which are related to him/her also he/she should not have placed a bid on the project(primary condition). So that is why I started my aggregation query from bid documents. If you have a better way please tell me!Thank you

Comment: But you have the information of engineer "x", like `license` and `location` before starting the aggregation, right? otherwise we wouldn't know which engineer we would match with.

Comment: yes we will have the engineers location and licence and projects location and licence before starting the aggregation

Comment: How does `match.location` and `match.licence` look like, in your aggregation?

Comment: @TheeSritabtim match.location = ['Moscow' , 'Berlin']
match.licence = ['civil engineer' , 'cs engineer']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you can't separate `location` from `licence`, otherwise they'll get matched independently, like what you tried to do.

Instead you should keep them as pairs together, the key here is to use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

```
// note that id's are not included
const professions = [
  {
    location: "Moscow",
    licence: "civil engineer"
  },
  {
    location: "Berlin",
    licence: "cs engineer"
  }
]
```

Then you can use the following query

```
const projects = BidHistory.aggregate([{
  {
    $match: {
      'bids.engineerID': { $ne: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.engineer.id) }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "projects",
      localField: "projectID",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "project"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "project": {
        $elemMatch: {
          $or: professions // use matching professions here
        }
      }
    }
  },
/* Bonus: to get projects at top level add following stages */
  {
    $unwind: '$project'
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$project' }
  }
}])
```